# What is the size of Gnome's top bar?

Tags: gnome, display-resolution

In order to run windowed programs at the maximum possible size I can set their resolution to the resolution of my monitor, but then there are several pixels off-screen below the window because the window is positioned below the Gnome Top Bar.

If I knew the size of the top-bar I could account for that, is there a way to find out what size it is exactly?

Comment: You can determine what is right by trial and error until it looks right.

Comment: settings , display, adjust for tv is worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maximize an active window
2. Then measure its size
3. Apply the new calculated size on your target program window

Just a theory, not sure if `wmctrl` and `xdotool` are still working fine with Wayland.

```
user@Bee3:~/Desktop$ wmctrl -lG
0x01600003 -1 136  54   1168 699  Bee3 @!68,27;BDHF  <-- desktop may be
0x02a0000a  0 454  60   912  664  Bee3 user@Bee3: ~/Desktop
user@Bee3:~/Desktop$ wmctrl -lG
0x01600003 -1 136  54   1168 699  Bee3 @!68,27;BDHF
0x02a0000a  0 136  54   1168 699  Bee3 user@Bee3: ~/Desktop  <-- terminal window maximized
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of Gnome and which shell theme you're using.  Take a look at the settings for Top Bar in your gnome-shell.css file.